# Crash If The Chinese Is Included In Feature File

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

The feature file is as below which is included Chinese:

```
Feature: Splash feature
Scenario: As a user I can know the introduction of the app
    Given I wait for the view with id "introduce" to appear
    When I drag from 0:600 to 700:600 moving with 5 steps
    And I swipe right
    And I swipe right
    Then I see "开始使用"
```

When execute command calabash-android run app-dev-debug.apk.  It occurs crash. 
 What's the problem and how to solve it?

I have tried chcp 65001 and 936. That is not OK.

My env is as below:

```
Win7 GBK version
ruby 2.2.4p230
calabash-android 0.7.3
cucumber 2.3.3
```

Comment: Does your app crash?  Does cucumber raise an error?  More details please.

Comment: app doesn't crash, but the cucumber crash as below:
"[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information."

Comment: Do you have "# encoding: utf-8" at the top of your feature file?

Comment: I have added "# encoding: utf-8" at the top of feature file. But still not work.

Comment: When I use command "calabash-android run app-dev-debug.apk > a.txt" to try to output the log to a text file, find that the crash will not happen. Is it means that the crash is triggered by Chinese wording output to the command windows?